# Understanding McCabe's Cyclomatic complexity

Tags: cyclomatic-complexity, code-complexity

McCabe's cyclomatic complexity measure is computed as follows:

V = e - n + 2

where e = number of edges; n = number of nodes

Why 2 is added to (e-n) in order to obtain the result?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be similar to [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler%27s_formula) for planar graphs, and since I'm no fan of McCabe, I suppose they use it to seem more science-y.

I say similar because I don't see how, in the question, if 'n' is the number of nodes, why that would be different from the number of vertices.